# How to rsync chronologically starting with the most recent files

Tags: find, rsync

I have the following directory structure

```
item_1
item_12
item_33
..etc..
```

Now I would like to start rsyncing from the most recent files and chronologically sync down the list.

Or option 2: How to rsync directories that are not older than 1 week.

Background: I have several TB of data on a slow drive and need to sync them onto a fast drive. Now skipping syncing all data at once, I would like to just sync recent data.

Is it possible to do it just with rsync, or do I have to work with find in combination with rsync?

Answer (score 4):

`rsync` always sorts its source files, as that makes it much easier to compare the file list on the destination to find files that have been removed, new files that have been added, and files that have been updated.

In the extreme case you could find the most recent files and run `rsync` with just a single source file multiple times; whether that is efficient is doubtful.

You need to decide how to select which directories to sync. If you only look at the directory timestamp, then you might miss files within that directory that have been updated or even subdirectories and files within those.

If you really really only want to sync recent files, and not worry about deleting files on the destination that have been removed from the source, then you could use something like:

```
find topdir -mtime -7 -type f -print0 > /tmp/list-of-files
rsync -ptgo --files-from=/tmp/list-of-files --from0 ./ destinationdir/
```

This first builds a list of files that are less than 7 days old, and stores them in a temporary file, null-terminated (so that filenames with spaces and newlines embedded still work correctly). Note that you probably need to find a secure place to put this list, as putting it in `/tmp` opens you to security issues, especially with a fixed name as above.

Next you tell `rsync` to transfer these files, preserving permissions, timestamps, group and user settings.

Comment: What if we remove `-print0` and `--from0` and just use `-print`? Is there a reason to use `0`?

Comment: I would cut it down to `cd /source/ && rsync -avn --files-from=<(find . -mtime -7 -print) . /destination/`

Comment: @Aley As I wrote that protects filenames that might contain an embedded newline. As in `touch "$(echo -en 'test\n123')"`

Comment: With `-a` and `find` without a test for files you will include directories which will be transferred recursively, including any files that may be much older. Worst case `.` is listed...

Comment: aha I see. okay what if i need to check the date of item_N directory only and sync accordingly. So this would be `cd /source/ && rsync -avn --files-from=<(find . -maxdepth 1 -mtime -7 -print0) --from0 . /destination/`